# Adding a QSlider using Qt

Tags: qt, user-interface, qslider

I would like to add a QSlider in a QToolButton just like volume control in windows OS.
Can any body help me how to achieve this in Qt?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to add it to a QToolBar, or really "in" a QToolButton?

Comment: yes, i want to add a Qtoolbutton to Qtoolbar and a click on toolbutton should open the vertical qslider. And the problem i have is qtoolbutton menu accepts only actions not widgets.

Answer (score 5):

I believe what you are looking for is [QWidgetAction](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidgetaction.html).

It essentially allows you to place a `QWidget` into a `QAction`.